# spin independent observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, eigenvalue, observables

Let's consider a spin independent observable $O$ (the terms of the operator don't depend upon the spin operator).

If we are interested to find an eigenfunctions' basis of the wave-functions' space, should we ignore the existence of the spin when solving the eigenvalue problem?

Is it just a simplification option or we must do it to avoid some mathematical contradictions?

If we do calculation without spin, what is the proof that the matrix of the whole operator (with spin consideration) will be a simple diagonal duplication of the first one?

Comment: What do you mean "assume the existence of spin" and what is a "spin-independent observable"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Please check the question again. I just edited it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "eigenfunctions' basis of the wave-functions' space".

Comment: Wave-functions' space is the Hilbert that is the set of the all possible wave-functions of a quantum system. An eigenfunctions' basis is a basis made of wave-functions that are "eigen-vector" of the considered observable.

Comment: I got the right answer, but people unable to answer has just close the question: unbelievable and crazy. The answer is here and they claim the question is not clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the kinetic energy observable $T$ for a spin-1/2 particle in 3D space. The particle's Hilbert space is technically ${\mathfrak H} = L^2({\mathbb R}^3) \otimes {\mathbb C}^2$, yet the kinetic energy operator $T$ is first defined on $L^2({\mathbb R}^3)$, where its eigenfunctions $\Psi_{\bf p}({\bf x})$ are easily found. The extension of $T$ to  $L^2({\mathbb R}^3) \otimes {\mathbb C}^2$ is simply $T \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2}$, where $I_{{\mathbb C}^2}$ is the identity operator on ${\mathbb C}^2$. Given an arbitrary spin basis $|\uparrow>, |\downarrow>$, the eigenfunctions of $T \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2}$ become the direct products $\Psi_{\bf p} \otimes |\uparrow>$, $\Psi_{\bf p} \otimes |\downarrow>$. The same procedure applies whenever an observable $O$ is first defined on one Hilbert space and must be extended to a direct product of spaces.

So the answer to your question is yes, the standard procedure is to start with the observable $O$ as defined in the absence of spin and then construct the direct product extension to account for spin.

Comment: Nice answer. It allowed me to understand the problem. Actually, the terms of the operator don't depend upon the spin operator (but not:  Its action on any wave-function doesn't depend of its spin state)! Right?

Comment: @aayyachi Yes, on both accounts. The operator does not include spin contributions, or else whatever contributions there are, they are proportional to I_ℂ2, for example something like σiσj  + σjσi = 2δ_ij I_ℂ2 for spin-1/2 (σi being the Pauli matrices). As for the action of the operator, say you have an entangled state Ψ = Ψ↑( **x** )| ↑〉+  Ψ↓( **x** )| ↓〉. The action of *T* ⊗I_ℂ2  on it produces *T* ⊗I_ℂ2 Ψ = [ *T* Ψ↑( **x** )] | ↑〉+  [ *T* Ψ↓( **x** )] | ↓〉, meaning *T* acts on the Ψ↑, Ψ↓ components, but not on the spin states themselves.

Comment: Let's consider a random basis $(ϕ_{i,+},ϕ_{i,−})_i$ of the space and call $(a_{i,+},a_{i,−})_i$ the components of a state-function and $(b_{i,+},b_{i,−})_i$ those of its image by $O$. Could I understand that: if $(a_{i,+})_i=(a_{i,−})_i$ then $(b_{i,+})i=(b_{i,−})_i$ ?

Comment: To deduce the matrix of the final operator from the reduced one (see question edit please) by simple diagonal duplication, we still have to proof that the anti-diagonal corner blocks are $0$. If $O$ commutes with the spin operator, we are done. Could you add an extra answer please?

Comment: @aayyachi If the basis vectors $φ_{i±}$ are of the direct product type, $φ_{i±} = φ_i \otimes | ± >$, then  $a_{i+} = a_{i-} = a_i$ gives $\sum_i{(a_{i+}\phi_{i+} + a_{i-}\phi_{i-})} = (\sum_i{a_i \phi_i}) \otimes ( | +>  +  |-> )$ and by linearity  $O \sum_i{(a_{i+}\phi_{i+} + (a_{i-}\phi_{i-})} = (\sum_i{a_i(O \phi_i)}) \otimes ( | +>  +  |-> )$, so indeed you have $b_{i+} = b_{i-} = b_i$.  If $φ_{i±} \neq φ_i \otimes | ± >$, then no, the b-s are not generally equal.

Comment: @aayyachi Defining the extension of $O$ in the presence of spin as $O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2}$ implies that $<\uparrow| O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2} | \uparrow> = <\downarrow| O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2} | \downarrow> = O$ and $<\uparrow| O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2} | \downarrow> = <\downarrow| O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2} | \uparrow> = 0$. The notation cuts corners by omitting contributions from $L^2({\mathbb R}^3)$, but conveys the basic idea. So yes, this means $O \otimes I_{{\mathbb C}^2}$ commutes with the spin operators and the anti-diagonal blocks are null.

Comment: I got the right answer, but people unable to answer has just close the question: unbelievable and crazy. The answer is here and they claim the question is not clear!

Comment: @aayyachi Those people could answer, but chose not to. Sorry, it's not your fault, really.

Comment: :) I don't understand why they claim it's not clear and they close it